# FFMPEG not converting mp3 to ogg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have a php upload script that converts MP3 files after they have been uploaded. I am keeping the mp3 file which is why I am doing it afterwards. A copy is created and then that is converted to ogg. The problem i am having is with FFMPEG as it is just not doing anything. I have never used FFMPEG or a tool like it before, nor have I used PHP's exec() function so I really have no idea how to use it but I have had a thorough look around for my answer before I came here.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$target_path."".$hash_filename.".".$path_extension."  ".$hash_filename.".ogg");
```

What the function could look like with data instead of variables:

```
ffmpeg -i ../uploads/ee78d5deb564901626067cc0008456ed.mp3 ee78d5deb564901626067cc0008456ed.ogg
```

I have checked with SSH and FFMPEG is located under the usual `usr/bin/ffmpeg`. I wondered if I should be targeting the file from where FFMPEG is or where the phpscript is but I have had no luck with either. Perhaps I am still targeting it from the wrong place?

I have checked and the codecs required for mp3 to ogg conversion are installed. I did also try adding those codecs into the command but the same thing happened. I understand FFMPEG automatically chooses which codecs to use so I ommited them.

Comment: You first need to determine if you have an issue with ffmpeg or with PHP. Try running ffmpeg manually from command-line and include the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I did try that but the input file is not found. I am not sure where I should be targetting the input file from. Can you help me/

Comment: Provide the full path to the input file or navigate to the directory containing the input file and then run: `ffmpeg -i ee78d5deb564901626067cc0008456ed.mp3 -codec:a libvorbis -q:a 3 output.ogg`. I told ffmpeg use the encoder named `libvorbis` because the default for ogg output is the encoder `flac`.